# C# Reflection CompileAssemblyFromSource slow

Tags: c#, reflection

I've some problems with reflection:

In my code I dynamically load c# code from database, compile it and load some object from that library. All that works, but the compilation made by CompileAssemblyFromSource is very very slow (about 60s).

I tried to compile the same c# code with Visual Studio 2015 and the build phase took less than 1s...

What's wrong? Is CompileAssemblyFromSource so slow?

Comment: .Net version you are using?  Also is the 60s timing on the same machine as your VisualStudio timing?  What is the result if you use CompileAssemblyFromSource in a dummy project on your local machine?

Comment: .Net 4.5.1. Visual Studio timing is on my development pc. No development environment on my server.

Comment: "but the compilation made by CompileAssemblyFromSource is very very slow (about 60s)" thus that is a timing on the server.  CompileAssemblyFromSource  is not inherently slow, so there are several possibilities, one is that the _server_ is slow at compiling for whatever reason, there are lots of others.  To help find the problem I am saying on your development machine compile the code with CompileAssemblyFromSource in as close a way as you can to how its done on the sever and time that. and post the results.  Are you SURE your 60s is compile time and not (say) extract from DB + compile time?

Comment: You'll have to look for environment causes for a delay that long.  That usually isn't very hard, creating executable files at runtime forever gets you into a battle with the kind of software that doesn't think much about shenanigans like that.  You'll have to add an exclusion in your anti-malware product.  Hard to do btw, you never want to do so for your TEMP directory.  At least make it smarter and do this only when the dbase content changed.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Code is generated in the TEMP directory regardless of whether GenerateInMemory is set to true. By setting the Tempfiles property in CompilerParameters to a non-existing drive/directory this will not happen:

```
     parameters.TempFiles = new TempFileCollection(@"B:\NonExistingDirectory");
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and this suggestion didn't solved it for me