# c# CompileAssemblyFromSource slower than Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dynamic-compilation

I've a simple class (600 lines) that I compiling by CompileAssemblyFromSource method.

This method take over than 1 minute to finish, I tried to compile the code directly in Visual Studio and it takes less than one second...

What's wrong? How can I speed up my dynamic compilation?

Thare are some options That I can try?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you debug/profile your process to see what step exactly takes so long? Without your code nobody can say what might be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723406/c-sharp-reflection-compileassemblyfromsource-slow